# Number between brackets next to interface name

Tags: terminal, network, command-line

What is the number between brackets next to the interface name in `ifconfig` output?
In the following output i.e. `(17)`

```
en0 (17):
  inet address  192.168.4.5
```

**EDIT**
As requested I add more info.
I was using `ifconfig` on Ventura but this called the Homebrew command instead the native one.
Using `/sbin/ifconfig` i got the output without the brackets.

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
...
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the GNU `ifconfig` tool that comes when installing inetutils from HomeBrew (for example).

The number in the brackets is just an ID/index number - it is not listed when using the standard, macOS `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Yes! I was not aware I was using Homebrew `ifconfig` and not the native one. 
Thank you!